# How to ignore unicode character with regex in python 3?

Tags: python, regex, non-unicode

I am trying to parse a vocabulary list with a lot of unicode characters inside. I DONT want to catch these charaters, I want to handel them like normal charaters if possibel. My Data:

```
en  antropologi     /ɑntrupulu¹giː/     antropologien, antropologier, antropologiene    an anthropology     01A
en  arkitektur  /ɑrkitek¹tʉːr/  arkitekturen, arkitekturerarkitekturene     an architecture     01A
ei  avis    /ɑ¹viːs/    avisa, aviser, avisene  a newspaper     01P
    Barcelona   /bɑʃe¹luːnɑ/        proper name     01M
    bare    /²bɑːre/        just, only  01M
    bare bra!   /bɑre ¹brɑː/        just fine!  01M
en  bensinstasjon   /ben¹siːnstɑˌʃuːn/  bensinstasjonen, bensinstasjoner, bensinstasjonene  a petrol station    01P
```

I want to have two groups reggex: 
group(1): `Includes all vocabulary without the last "capter-ID"`
group(2): `Only "capter-ID"`

Example:
group(1): `en     antropologi     /ɑntrupulu¹giː/     antropologien, antropologier, antropologiene    an anthropology`
group(2): `01A`

I tried the follwing search-algorithms which work fine on https://regex101.com/ which I used for debugging:
"(.+)(01\S)\n" works as well as "(\D+)(01\S)\n"

This is my code and the Error I get:

```py
import re

def readTemplate(filepath): #reading a file
    try:
        with open(filepath, "r") as template:
            data = template.read()
        return data
    except:
        return False

def parseData(data): #parse file data
    voc = []
    cap = []

    regexMatch = re.compile("(.+)(01\S)\n").finditer(data)
    for matches in regexMatch:
        voc.append(str(matches.group(1)))
        cap.append(str(matches.group(2)))

    return voc, cap

#-----------------------------Main Prog.-----------------------------

data = readTemplate('Vocubulary.txt') #open file
voc, cap = parseData(data) #parse Data
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/User...Vocabulary.py", line 25, in <module>
    voc, cap = parseData(data) #parse Data
  File "C:/Users...Vocabulary.py", line 15, in parseData
    regexMatch = re.compile("(.+)(01\S)\n").finditer(data)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What if you add `data = ""` right below `def readTemplate(filepath):`? In `parserData`, add a condition `if data:` before parsing. See https://ideone.com/ly8bLN (not tested)

Answer (score -1):

While the code works without errors on my machine (linux), you could try using [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).

```
regexMatch = re.compile(r"(.+)(01\S)\n").finditer(data)
```